# django model field in url

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I've been learning django for a little bit now but I've ran myself into the ground with this one. I've been looking for an answer for two days and, annoyingly, I think I stumbled across it at one stage but I didnt realise until later that I forgot to change the template (by which time I forgot what post I read so I could recreate it).

I'm trying to create something where users can signup then create a "channel" to store their stuff. I have that working just fine, but now I want to make it so the URL's look nicer (like Github or youtube).

I'd like the URL's to display as "example.com/channels/*channel-name*" rather than "example.com/channels/1"

This is what I have so far:

**url:**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', channel_views.DetailView.as_view(), name="channel-detail"),
```

(note: when slug is changed out for `(?P< pk >[0-9]+)` it works)

**views**:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Channel
    template_name = 'channels/channel-detail.html'
```

**models**

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('channels:channel-detail', kwargs={'slug':self.name})
```

**index.html:**

```
<a class="channel-link text-center" href="{% url 'channels:channel-detail' channel.id %}">{{channel.name}}</a>
```

I feel like I need to run the "name" field through slugify then call that in the HTML template instead of `channel.id`?

Comment: You should store a separate slug field which is auto-populated from the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the detail view know that you are using the name for the slug field

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Channel
    template_name = 'channels/channel-detail.html'
    slug_field = 'name'
```

Though it isn't unique at preset, so could cause you problems.

Better would be to add an extra slug field, and as you suggested populate it by running the name through slugify, and making sure that it is unique.

Have a look in the get_object() method here, to see how the object is selected using primary keys or slugs:

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: Thank you so much! 

It took a while but I worked out the problem. I needed to change the slug_field in the view.py to the 'slug' field rather than name, then call channels.slug in the HTML template.